# Spring Hello Dependency Injection @Autowired throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, servlets, autowired

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**`TestController.java`:**

```
package com.mypack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test
 */
@WebServlet("/test")
@Controller
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestManager testManager;

    
    public TestManager getTestManager() {
        return testManager;
    }

    public void setTestManager(TestManager testManager) {
        this.testManager = testManager;
    }

    public TestController() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        String name=testManager.getName();
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        pw.write(name);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

**`TestManager.java`:**

```
package com.mypack;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("testManager")
public class TestManager {
    
    @Autowired
    private TestDao testDao;
    
    public String getName(){
        return testDao.getName();
    }

    public TestDao getTestDao() {
        return testDao;
    }

    public void setTestDao(TestDao testDao) {
        this.testDao = testDao;
    }
}
```

**`TestDao.java`:**

```
package com.mypack;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("testDao")
public class TestDao {
    public String getName(){
        return "Randhir";
    }
}
```

**`spring.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Enable Spring Application Context -->
    <context:spring-configured />
    
    <!-- Scan class file in class path for annotated component -> @Component, @Repository, @Service, and @Controller  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypack" />
    
</beans>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SpringIOCWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
    
</web-app>
```

**Server Console:**

```
INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:39 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:39 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jan 21 19:50:39 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:39 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring.xml]
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:40 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 731 ms
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2836 ms
Jan 21, 2017 7:50:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.mypack.TestController] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mypack.TestController.doGet(TestController.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

IOC Container will instantiate the bean and assign the object reference using setter method. Is my concept is right ?

But here `@Autowired` doesn't assign the object reference. Till I have used using main method with `ApplicationContext` and `getBean` to learn Spring.

But how the bean configuration works with servlet?

Comment: You need to add a comment to each source code line mentioned in a stack trace so that we know which line is which.

Comment: Once @Autowired annotation is used, you dont need setter methods to inject dependencies.

Comment: A Spring `@Controller` is *not* a Servlet (`@WebServlet` / `HttpServlet`). The `@WebServlet` annotation means that the `HttpServlet` is loaded directly by the Servlet Container (Tomcat, Jetty, ...), bypassing the Spring Container, which means that the `@Autowired` is not applied. That is confirmed by the stacktrace, by the fact that there is no Spring classes in the stack. You should re-read the [Spring Web MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) manual, so you know what a Controller is, and how to write one.

Answer (score 2):

Your `testManager` is null.
You are mixing Servlet and Spring controllers.

You should use Spring dispatcher servlet :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The DispatcherServlet is one unique servlet, like a front controller (in a MVC2 pattern), that dispatches the request to Spring controllers (a spring component).

Then in your controller TestController, remove the inheritance of HttpServlet and override methods (doGet, doPost..), and use `@RequestMapping`.

In that way you will use the dependency injection of Spring framework.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestManager testManager;

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        String name=testManager.getName();
        return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using servlet and not controller you could autowire it with the code

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory ctx;

    @Autowired
    private TestManager testManager;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        ctx = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        ctx.autowireBean(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

You already have integrated Spring using its own context listener

```xml
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```